# Why did France start issuing non-transferable taxi licenses in 2015?

Tags: france, transportation

According to a [2016 EU document](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/sites/transport/files/2016-09-26-pax-transport-taxi-hirecar-w-driver-ridesharing-country-reports.pdf) taxi licenses issued in France before 2015 remain transferable, but those issued thereafter are not.

> Under the French system, the licences are called “parking permits” (autorisation de stationnement or ADS). At the national level, Section 2 of the Transport Code regulates the issuance and transfer of new licences. New licences are valid for five years. As a general rule, from the enactment of Article L3121-2 of the 2014 Bill, licences may not be transferred for consideration. The licences issued before the reform remain tradable under certain circumstances. The current average price in France for tradable licences is around EUR 100,000. In order to obtain a taxi licence, the applicant must hold a professional card, which is the document that includes the certificate of professional competence. This certificate is obtained after a period of training and after having passed an examination divided into two parts (national and departmental) with theoretical and practical tests. Once the candidate has successfully passed the exam, he may enrol in the waiting list for free taxi licences. The application for the licences must be renewed every year. In Paris, there are currently 46,871 pending applications.

What motivated this change, i.e. the introduction of non-transferable licenses in France?